# Найти фирму которая наибольшее количество раз выступала в роли истца

Tags: c++, база-данных, функции

Добрый день! 
Помогите написать функцию. Вопрос жизни и смерти.
Есть база данных и в которую надо дописать функцию. Функция должна определить фирму которая наибольшее количество раз выступала в роли истца.
Я думаю что сначала надо отсортировать фирмы которые выступали в роли истца, а потом среди них найти фирму которая самое большое количество раз выступала истцом, то есть максимальный элемент. Только как это все записать в код я не знаю.

Вот структура базы данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct DATA{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

struct vidp {
int telefon;
char nazvFirm[15];
};

struct sprava{
DATA data;
char predmet[20];
vidp v;
vidp obv;
};

sprava* array_of_sprava=new sprava[50];
FILE* Fs;
int nzap=0;

int i=0,h=0,g=0;


int reading()//чтение;
{
if ((Fs=fopen("my.dat","rb"))==NULL)
{
      cout<<("Не можу відкрити файл\n");
      return 0; }
do
   {
     fread(&array_of_sprava[nzap],sizeof(sprava),1,Fs);
     nzap++;
     if (feof(Fs)) break;

   } while(1);

nzap--;

cout<<"Зчитування закінчено\n";
fclose(Fs); // Закрываем файл
system("pause");
return 0;
}

int outp_to_file(){ // Вывод в файл
FILE* Fs;
if ((Fs=fopen("my.dat","wb"))==NULL)
{
 cout<<("Файл не створений!\n");
 return 0;
}
for (int i=0;i<nzap;i++)
  fwrite(&array_of_sprava[i],sizeof(sprava),1,Fs);
cout<<("Файл створений!");
fclose(Fs);
system("pause");
}



int input_in_array(){//ввод в масив;
int q=1;
while (q!=0)
{
cout<<"\nВведіть день справи: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].data.day;
cout<<"\nВведіть місяц справи: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].data.month;
cout<<"\nВведіть рік справи: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].data.year;
cout<<"\nВведіть придмет справи: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].predmet;
cout<<"\nВведіть телефон позивача: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].v.telefon;
cout<<"\nВведіть фірму позивача: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].v.nazvFirm;
cout<<"\nВведіть телефон обвинувачуваного: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].obv.telefon;
cout<<"\nВведіть фірму обвинувачуваного: ";
cin>>array_of_sprava[nzap].obv.nazvFirm;
nzap++;
cout<<"\nВведіть 0 для закінчення запису або будь-яке число для      продовження: ";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n";

}
}

int VivEkran()// Вывод на экран
{system("cls");
for(int i=0;i<nzap;i++)
{
  cout<<"Запис №"<<i+1<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ День справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.day<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Місяць справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.month<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Рік справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.year<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Предмет справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].predmet<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Телевон позивача: "<<array_of_sprava[i].v.telefon<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Фірма позивача: "<<array_of_sprava[i].v.nazvFirm<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Телефон обвинувачуваного: "   <<array_of_sprava[i].obv.telefon<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Фірма обвинувачуваного: "<<array_of_sprava[i].obv.nazvFirm<<"\n";
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
  }

  int newbase()// создать новую базу данных
  { system("cls");
  cout<<"База даних\n";
  string v;
  cout<<"Введіть назву нової бази даних\n";
  cin>>v;
  FILE* Fs;

  if ((Fs=fopen(v.c_str(),"wb"))==NULL)
  {
  cout<<("Файл не створений\n");

  system("pause");return 0;
  }
 for (int i=0;i<nzap;i++)
 fwrite(&array_of_sprava[nzap],sizeof(sprava),1,Fs);
 cout<<("Файл створений\n");
 system("pause");
 fclose(Fs);
 return 0;
 }



 void poisk(){ // поиск
 cout<<"Введіть рік справи: ";
 int y;
 cin >> y;
 bool not_found = true;
 for (int i=0;i<nzap;i++) {
    if (array_of_sprava[i].data.year==y) {
  cout<<"Запис №"<<i+1<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ День справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.day<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Місяць справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.month<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Рік справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].data.year<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Предмет справи: "<<array_of_sprava[i].predmet<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Телевон позивача: "<<array_of_sprava[i].v.telefon<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Фірма позивача: "<<array_of_sprava[i].v.nazvFirm<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Телефон обвинувачуваного: "<<array_of_sprava[i].obv.telefon<<"\n";
  cout<<"\ Фірма обвинувачуваного: " <<array_of_sprava[i].obv.nazvFirm<<"\n";
  system("pause");
         not_found = false;
    }
   }
   if (not_found) {
    cout<<"Дані за цей рік не знайдені\n";
     system("pause");
    }
   }   



   int main()// меню
   {setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Ukr");
   system("chcp 1251");
   int rez=1;
   while(rez!=0)
   {
   system("cls");
   cout<<"База даних\n";
   cout<<"Меню\n";
   cout<<"1 - Додати дані ;\n";
   cout<<"2 - Введення даних в файл;\n";
   cout<<"3 - Зчитати дані з файлу;\n";
   cout<<"4 - Вивести всі дані на екран;\n";
   cout<<"5 - Пошук по року;\n";
   cout<<"6 - Фірма яка найчастіше була позивачем;\n";
   cout<<"7 - Створеня нової бази даних;\n";
   cout<<"0 - Вихід;\n";
   cout<<nzap<<":";
   cin>>rez;
   switch(rez)
   {
   case 1:input_in_array();break;
   case 2:outp_to_file();break;
   case 3:reading();break;
   case 4:VivEkran();break;
   case 5:poisk();break;
   // case 6:фирма которая чаще была истцом();break;
  case 7:newbase();break;
  case 0: outp_to_file();exit(0);break;
  default :break;
  }}
  }
```

Comment: Если база данных - используйте SQL.

Comment: я не знаю что такое SQL.

Comment: Мне на с++ дописать функцию, а как ее написать я ни имею не малейшего понятия.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Я сам все написал!